# Cant get child window variable value on my parent window

Tags: c#, wpf

Description - I have main window having status label which shows status in the form of connected and disconnected. When i create a object(parent window) in child window and set label status it wont be reflected in parent window. .I also tried, took a one Boolean variable and set to value 1 in child window code,but when i access that variable in parent window ,i got by default value that is zero.

```
/// My parent window code

public partial class MainWindow : Window
{  
    public CompSetting obj = new CompSetting();
    public MainWindow()
    {   
       InitializeComponent();
    }

    private void click(object sender, MouseButtonEventArgs e)
    {
        CompSetting compPortseting = new CompSetting();
        compPortseting.ShowDialog();
    }

    private void button_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        if (obj.flag  == 1) // Here i get by defult value 0 . but already set to 1 on child window. In short cant access flag variable value.
        {
            LblPortStatus_lable.Content = "chetas";
        }
        else
        {
            LblPortStatus_lable.Content = "rahul";
        }
    }
}

// My child window code 
public partial class CompSetting : Window
{ 
    public  int flag  ;
    public CompSetting()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    private void button_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        flag = 1;
    }
}
```

Comment: On the click event use `obj` instead of `compPortseting`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
private void click(object sender, MouseButtonEventArgs e)
{
    if(obj != null)
    {
        obj.ShowDialog();
    }
}
```

Do not create a new object, just use the existing one.

**Extra**

Instead of creating an instance of the child window consider creating an instance of a settings object. The child window would then get a reference to the settings object and modify it:

```
public partial class MainWindow : Window
{  
    public CompSetting settings = new CompSetting();
    public MainWindow()
    {   
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    private void click(object sender, MouseButtonEventArgs e)
    {
        var settingsDialog = new SettingDialog(settings);
        settingsDialog.ShowDialog();
    }

    private void button_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        if (settings.Flag  == 1) 
        {
            LblPortStatus_lable.Content = "chetas";
        }
        else
        {
            LblPortStatus_lable.Content = "rahul";
        }
    }
}

// My child window code 
public partial class SettingDialog : Window
{ 
    private CompSettings settings

    public SettingsDialog(CompSettings settings)
    {
        this.settings = settings;
    }

    private void button_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        this.settings.Flag = 1;
    }
}

public class CompSettings
{
    public int Flag;
}
```

Comment: not getting result sir, i want flag variable value which is set in the child window.

Comment: Yes I know that that is what you want and using the code I posted should work unless you are (re)setting the setting/obj reference in code you didn't post. Did you post all your code?

Comment: What code are you referring to, the first quick answer or the longer second code fragment?